# Can I get the gyroscope data from my phone to make a makeshift racing sim rig for pc

Tags: android, controller, gyroscope

I live in a temporary place for a short period of time and I don't have the budget or space for a racing sim rig. So I want to make my own rig using the gyroscope from my phone and triggers from my controller.

Basically, instead of the left stick on the controller I want to rotate my phone for the x-axis controls and for gas and brakes I'll keep using the LT and RT.

I haven't tried coding anything yet since I don't even know if that's possible.

Comment: I think Android devices have no gyroscope.

Comment: @blackapps -- There are enough [android devices](https://www.91mobiles.com/list-of-phones/gyroscope-sensor-phones) with a [gyroscope](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_GYROSCOPE)

Comment: @Krokomot, thank you. Interesting. Wonder how they work.

Comment: @blackapps -- [Vibrating structure gyroscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrating_structure_gyroscope) as [MEMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEMS)

Comment: Thank you. An incredible new world opened for me.

Answer (score 0):

you could try with Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE in android. Read more at [GYROSCOPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#sensor.type_gyroscope:)

Or combine with another sensor like **Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER** , **Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD** , **Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR** .

You should check your device supported each sensor type above or not